# CoffeeScript indentation problems in Emacs

Tags: emacs, coffeescript, indentation

I am not even sure how to ask this. It feels like anytime I misindent one place in Emacs for a bigger CoffeeScript file, I end up spending a long time looking for the misindentation.  Is there a better `coffeescript.el` mode file that can solve this?  Anybody running into similar problem? What is the best practice on that? It gets to a point I am kind of afraid to make change to that CoffeeScript file.

Comment: Indentation space solves part of the problem.  But what I was referring to is more of a problem relating to bigger coffeescript file.  How I could split up the files for better readability and maintainability?  Obviously, now I would be using a framework to have better abstraction if I implement this now.  But for older/longer coffeescript file that I didn't use any framework for, do I have to refactor the whole thing or what are some of the practices on separating out files for better readability?

Comment: I apologize for my misleading question title.  I know the author of coffee-mode did a lot and my question really wasn't aiming at that so much but instead my ignorance of having a more structured way of laying out coffeescript and coffeescript files in general.  Like a best practice of abstraction without a framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The README on the [coffee-mode author page](https://github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode) describes how indentation works. In short, create a global variable `tab-width` either by putting `(setq tab-width 4)` in your `.emacs`, or by executing extended command `M-x set-variable RET tab-width RET 4`.

If this is still not the desirable behavior, then file a bug on the author's issues page.

Comment: Changing `tab-width` is not recommended unless you really know what you're getting into (e.g. it will make files look different in your editor than in other people's).  Better set `coffee-tab-width` and send a bug report that coffee-mode should not change `tab-width`.

Comment: why isn't using it recommended? It is buffer local and Emacs manual doesn't say anything about not using it.

Comment: This won't quite work all the time. Sometimes you must set `coffee-tab-width`, if you just set `tab-width` it will not override the (horribly chosen) default.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, Stefan.  I set this and it resolved my strange coffeescript tabbing.